# Need to add \" to a string

Tags: csvhelper

I have a string inside of one of my mapped columns that contains HTML such as `<font color = "navy">`. However, I need to export the data as `<font color = \"navy\">`. When I actually export, I get `<font color = \""navy\"">`.

I just added a plain stream writer object and the data comes out as `<font color = \"navy\">`

I currently add `rec.FieldLabel.Replace("\"", "\\\"")`. In the data set it shows up fine but when it is written using CsvHelper it adds an additional "

Comment: I saw a comment about the same type of issue at the bottom of this ticket. 
https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/458 made by RicardoGarciaM

Answer (score 0):

Just use three slashes:

- First to escape the next slash.
- Second is the escaped clash.
- The third is the slash escaping the following quotation mark

`\\\"`

So in your case the result would look like this:

```
<font color = \\\"navy\\\">
```

Comment: I guess I should have added that too. I currently add `rec.FieldLabel.Replace("\"", "\\\"")`. In the data set it shows up fine but when it is written using CsvHelper it adds an additional "

Answer (score 0):

You can set the escape character to a backslash instead of doubling the quote to escape it.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var records = new List<Foo>
        {
            new Foo{Id = 1, FieldLabel = "<font color = \"navy\">"}
        };

        using(var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out))
        {
            csv.Configuration.Escape = '\\';
            csv.WriteRecords(records);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FieldLabel { get; set; }
}
```

Your additional issue of an already escaped `\"` could potentially be solved by setting the quote character to a single quote instead of a double quote.  Unfortunately, if you have a single quote in your field, it will have to be escaped with whatever you set the escape character to.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var records = new List<Foo>
        {
            new Foo{Id = 1, FieldLabel = "\"<font color = \\\"navy\\\">\""}
        };

        using(var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out))
        {
            csv.Configuration.Escape = '\\';
            csv.Configuration.Quote = '\'';
            csv.WriteRecords(records);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you David. That works, but brings up an additional issue, how would you handle a legitimate escaped \"  so if the line above was in my original code it would have been listed as `'"\"<font color = \\\"navy\\\">\""`

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: '"<font color=\"navy\">"' It should be surrounded by an escaped quote but the escaped quotes around navy should really be treated as text.

Comment: The problem is CSV uses quotes to allow for fields to contain commas and line breaks, so a quote in the middle of a field needs to be escaped.  Now you are wanting to have both escaped and non-escaped quotes in the string.  You might have to manually remove the outer quotes and change the escaped quotes back to regular quotes.  I don't really see a good way to do it with configuration.

Comment: How about setting the quote character to a single quote `csv.Configuration.Quote = '\'';` instead of `csv.Configuration.Escape = '\\';`

Answer (score 0):

I made this a lot harder than it needed to be. CsvHelper is doing what it is supposed to be doing and that is escaping single double quotes. The way that I resolved this issue was to substitute the singe double quote in `<font color = "navy">` with `<font color = \&#34;navy\&#34;>` where " represents a single double quote.